# Wordpress theme Jobroller login page not displaying radio buttons

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a jobroller theme installed. When the login button is clicked which is present in top right corner, it displays two options with radio buttons. 1. Employer 2.Job-Seeker and Admin

I want to remove the first option i.e Employer and keep the Job-Seeker option. I have amended the file named register-form.php. The problem is that it works for two three times but then the radio button does not shows up and when the login form is filled and submit button is clicked it generates a role error, which means to choose role or check radio button and then submit.

I have tried to copy the register-form.php file again so that it work but it doesnt shows up. You can visit the page from this link.

http://www.selfreliance.com.pk/login/

The code of register-form.php is here.

```
<?php
/**
 * JobRoller Registration Form
 * Function outputs the registration form
 *
 *
 * @version 1.6.3
 * @author AppThemes
 * @package JobRoller
 * @copyright 2010 all rights reserved
 *
 */

add_action( 'jr_display_register_form', 'jr_register_form', 10, 2 );

function jr_register_form( $redirect = '', $role = 'job_lister' ) {
    global $posted, $app_abbr;

    if ( get_option('users_can_register') ) {

        if ( ! $redirect ) $redirect = get_permalink( JR_Dashboard_Page::get_id() );

        $show_password_fields = apply_filters('show_password_fields_on_registration', true);

?>
            <h2><?php _e('Create a free account', APP_TD); ?></h2>

            <form action="<?php echo appthemes_get_registration_url(); ?>" method="post" class="account_form" name="registerform" id="login-form">

                <?php 
                    if ( 'yes' == get_option('jr_allow_job_seekers') ) :
                        if ( ! $role || 'yes' == get_option( $app_abbr.'_allow_recruiters' ) ) :
                            ?>
                            <p class="role">

                                <?php if ( ! is_page( JR_Job_Submit_Page::get_id() ) ): ?>
                                    <label class="alt"><input type="radio" tabindex="6" name="role" value="job_seeker" <?php checked( isset($posted['role']) && $posted['role']=='job_seeker' ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'I am a <strong>Job Seeker</strong>', APP_TD ); ?></label>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </p>
                            <?php if ( 'yes' == get_option( $app_abbr.'_allow_recruiters' ) ) : ?>
                                <p class="role"><label class="alt"><input type="radio" tabindex="7" name="role" value="recruiter" <?php checked( isset($posted['role']) && $posted['role']=='recruiter' ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'I am a <strong>Recruiter</strong>', APP_TD ); ?></label></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php
                        elseif ( $role == 'job_lister' ) :
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="role" value="job_lister" />';
                        elseif ( $role == 'job_seeker') :
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="role" value="job_seeker" />';
                        elseif ( $role == 'recruiter' && 'yes' == get_option( $app_abbr.'_allow_recruiters' ) ) :
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="role" value="recruiter" />';
                        endif;
                    endif;
                ?>

                <div class="account_form_fields">

            <p>
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username', APP_TD); ?></label><br/>
                <input type="text" class="text" tabindex="8" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['user_login'])) echo esc_attr(stripslashes($_POST['user_login'])); ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="user_email"><?php _e('Email', APP_TD); ?></label><br/>
                <input type="text" class="text" tabindex="9" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['user_email'])) echo esc_attr(stripslashes($_POST['user_email'])); ?>" />
            </p>

                    <?php if ( $show_password_fields ) : ?>
                    <p>
                        <label for="your_password"><?php _e('Enter a password', APP_TD); ?></label><br/>
                        <input type="password" class="text" tabindex="10" name="pass1" id="pass1" value="" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="your_password_2"><?php _e('Enter password again', APP_TD); ?></label><br/>
                        <input type="password" class="text" tabindex="11" name="pass2" id="pass2" value="" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <div id="pass-strength-result" class="hide-if-no-js"><?php _e( 'Strength indicator', APP_TD ); ?></div>
                        <p><span class="description indicator-hint"><?php _e( 'Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).', APP_TD ); ?></span></p>
                    </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php
                    // include the spam checker if enabled();
                    if ( current_theme_supports( 'app-recaptcha' ) )
                        appthemes_recaptcha();
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( get_option('jr_terms_page_id') > 0 || 'yes' == get_option('jr_enable_terms_conditions') ) : ?><p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" tabindex="12" value="yes" id="terms" <?php if (isset($_POST['terms'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /> <label for="terms"><?php _e('I accept the ', APP_TD); ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( JR_Terms_Conditions_Page::get_id() ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e('terms &amp; conditions', APP_TD); ?></a>.</label>
                    </p><?php endif; ?>

                    <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>

                    <p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_attr($redirect); ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" class="submit" tabindex="13" name="register" value="<?php _e('Create Account &rarr;', APP_TD); ?>" />
                    </p>

                </div>

                <!-- autofocus the field -->
                <script type="text/javascript">try{document.getElementById('user_login').focus();}catch(e){}</script>

            </form>
<?php
    }
}
```

Comment: `* @copyright 2010 all rights reserved` Do you own the copyright to this code? Are you aware that all rights are no longer reserved once you post it here?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
 * JobRoller Registration Form.
 * Outputs the registration form.
 *
 * @version 1.6.3
 * @author AppThemes
 * @package JobRoller\Forms\Register
 * @copyright 2010 all rights reserved
 */

add_action( 'jr_display_register_form', 'jr_register_form', 10, 2 );

function jr_register_form( $redirect = '', $role = 'job_lister' ) {
    global $posted, $jr_options;

    if ( ! get_option('users_can_register') ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! $redirect ) {
        $redirect = get_permalink( JR_Dashboard_Page::get_id() );
    }

    $show_password_fields = apply_filters( 'show_password_fields_on_registration', true );
?>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Create a free account', APP_TD ); ?></h2>

    <form action="<?php echo appthemes_get_registration_url(); ?>" method="post" class="account_form" name="registerform" id="login-form">

        <?php  /* if ( $jr_options->jr_allow_job_seekers ): ?>

                <?php if ( ! $role || $jr_options->jr_allow_recruiters ): ?>
                    <p class="role">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="role" tabindex="5" value="job_lister" <?php checked( empty( $posted['role'] ) || $posted['role'] == 'job_lister' ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'I am an <strong>Employer</strong>', APP_TD ); ?></label >

                        <?php if ( ! is_page( JR_Job_Submit_Page::get_id() ) ): ?>
                            <label class="alt"><input type="radio" tabindex="6" name="role" value="job_seeker" <?php checked( isset( $posted['role'] ) && $posted['role'] == 'job_seeker' ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'I am a <strong>Job Seeker</strong>', APP_TD ); ?></label>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </p  ?>

                    <?php if ( $jr_options->jr_allow_recruiters ): ?>
                        <p class="role"><label class="alt"><input type="radio" tabindex="7" name="role" value="recruiter" <?php checked( isset( $posted['role'] ) && $posted['role'] == 'recruiter' ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'I am a <strong>Recruiter</strong>', APP_TD ); ?></label></p>
                    <?php endif;  ?>

                <?php
                    elseif ( $role == 'job_lister' ) :
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="role" value="job_lister" />';
                    elseif ( $role == 'job_seeker') :
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="role" value="job_seeker" />';
                    elseif ( $role == 'recruiter' && $jr_options->jr_allow_recruiters ) :
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="role" value="recruiter" />';
                    endif;
                ?>

        <?php endif; */  ?>

        <div class="account_form_fields">

            <p>
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'First Name', APP_TD ); ?></label><br/>
                <input type="text" class="text required" tabindex="8" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="<?php if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ): esc_attr_e( stripslashes( $_POST['user_login'] ) ); endif; ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Last Name', APP_TD ); ?></label><br/>
                <input type="text" class="text required" tabindex="8" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="<?php if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ): esc_attr_e( stripslashes( $_POST['user_login'] ) ); endif; ?>" />
            </p>



            <p>
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e( 'Username', APP_TD ); ?></label><br/>
                <input type="text" class="text required" tabindex="8" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="<?php if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) ): esc_attr_e( stripslashes( $_POST['user_login'] ) ); endif; ?>" />
            </p>

    <input type="hidden" name="role" value="job_seeker" />

            <p>
                <label for="user_email"><?php _e( 'Email', APP_TD ); ?></label><br/>
                <input type="text" class="text required" tabindex="9" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="<?php if ( isset( $_POST['user_email'] ) ): esc_attr_e( stripslashes( $_POST['user_email'] ) ); endif; ?>" />
            </p>

            <?php if ( $show_password_fields ) : ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="your_password"><?php _e( 'Enter a password', APP_TD ); ?></label><br/>
                    <input type="password" class="text required" tabindex="10" name="pass1" id="pass1" value="" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="your_password_2"><?php _e( 'Enter password again', APP_TD ); ?></label><br/>
                    <input type="password" class="text required" tabindex="10" name="pass2" id="pass" value="" />
                </p>

                <!--p>
                    <label for="your_password_2"><?php //_e( 'Enter password again', APP_TD ); ?></label><br/>
                    <input type="password" class="text required" tabindex="10" name="pass2" id="pass2" value="" />
                </p-->

                <br/><div id="pass-strength-result" class="hide-if-no-js"><?php _e( 'Strength indicator', APP_TD ); ?></div>

                <p><span class="description indicator-hint"><?php _e( 'Hint: The password should be at least seven characters long. To make it stronger, use upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols like ! " ? $ % ^ &amp; ).', APP_TD ); ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( jr_display_recaptcha('app-recaptcha') ): ?>
                    <?php appthemes_recaptcha(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfVZQwTAAAAAE-nJl6EWMz3QC8cHUvWCGvl7ioo"></div>

            <?php if ( $jr_options->jr_terms_page_id > 0 || $jr_options->jr_enable_terms_conditions ): ?>
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" tabindex="12" value="yes" id="terms" class="required" <?php checked( isset( $_POST['terms'] ) ); ?> />
                    <label for="terms"><?php _e( 'I accept the ', APP_TD ); ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( JR_Terms_Conditions_Page::get_id() ) ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e( 'terms &amp; conditions', APP_TD ); ?></a>.</label>
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>

            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $redirect ); ?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" tabindex="13" name="register" value="<?php _e( 'Create Account &rarr;', APP_TD ); ?>" />
            </p>

        </div>

        <!-- autofocus the field -->
        <script type="text/javascript">try{document.getElementById('user_login').focus();}catch(e){}</script>

    </form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are not encouraged (but they are allowed). Please also add a short explanation to what you did to solve the problem. That will make your answer more useful both for the person who asked the question, but also future visitors. Thank you!